# Is it correct this css to have a page with 2 rows?

Tags: html, css, yii

in my Yii project I want to have a template divided in 2 rows: the first must to be 90% height, the second 10%.
I have edited html and css in this way:

**/protected/view/layouts/main.php**

```
   <html>
   <!-- other tag -->
   <body>
   <div class="container" id="page">
    <?php echo $content; ?>

    <div class="clear"></div>

    </div>-->
   </div><!-- page -->
   <div id="footer">
        footer
   </div>
   </body>
```

**/css/main.css**

```
#page
{
    /*
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    */
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    background: white;
    position:absolute;
    height: 90%;
    /*border: 1px solid #C9E0ED;*/
} 

#footer
{
    top: 90%;
    padding: 20px;
    /*
    margin: 10px 20px;
    */
    font-size: 0.8em;
    text-align: center;
    /*border-top: 1px solid #C9E0ED;*/
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    width: auto;
}
```

The result is exactly as I wish but I would like know if my solution is correct and if the result is the same on every monitor resolution.
Thanks.

Comment: You can use this tool to test different screen sizes/resolutions :http://www.infobyip.com/testwebsiteresolution.php

Answer (score 1):

You have a nice approach with the `height` but don't need the `position:absolute` at all:

```
html,body {
  height:100%;
}
#page {
  height:90%;
}
#footer {
   height:10%;
}
```

With this you use just a couple of lines of CSS code.

---

<sub>This code is right ok in any resolution</sub>

The demo **http://jsfiddle.net/74ATy/4/**

Comment: Hi, your example doesn't works. This is the screen of my result using your solution.
<img src="http://oi39.tinypic.com/10f9ilw.jpg">

Comment: Have you seen the fiddle I Post? I guess your implements is wrong try to reproduce that in a fiddle

Comment: Yes, actually your solution works! I did not understand why my css doesn't correctly works if integrated in a cms